# Multimaster-FKIE can make node private?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the Multimaster-FKIE package to connect two ROS cores. I would need a certain node to be private to each ROS core. Is that possible? I need to run two Gazebo simulations with a package gazebo-ros-control which provides controllers for the robots, but it is only possible to run one of the node and so to control only one of the robots. I need to control both and couple them. One sends commands to the other. How can I achieve that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314374/multimaster-fkie-can-make-node-private?/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there is a parameter `~ignore_nodes` in `master_sync` node that does just that

so to make the `/gazebo` and `/gazebo_gui` nodes private, for example, this command is used when launching the `master_sync`  node:

```
rosrun master_sync_fkie master_sync _ignore_nodes:=['/gazebo','/gazebo_gui']
```

---

Originally posted by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) with karma: 308 on 2019-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0